# How to combine where statements in Zend Framework 2

Tags: sql, zend-framework2

That may be a silly question, but I just can't find any answer to it.

I have a simple query like 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE (x=a AND y=b) OR z=c' and I just can't find out how to implement that in ZF2.

I found a lot of information on Predicates and Where objects, but I can't find out how to combine that information into a query consisting of AND and OR.

I'd really appreciate it if someone can point me to the right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to add them using AND, you can simply pass them into the select object using an array, for example:

```
$select->where(array(
    'type'         => 'test,
    'some_field'   => '1'
));
```

If you want more complex Where queries, then you can use a Where object to build up a query:

```
$where = new \Zend\Db\Sql\Where();
$where->addPredicate(
        new \Zend\Db\Sql\Predicate\Like('some_field', '%'.$value.'%')
)
->OR->->equalTo('my_field', 'bob')
->AND->equalTo('my_field', 'hello');

$select->where($where);
```

Comment: Good thing i didn't post what i had tested - it looked so much more complicated :P

Comment: I've used all sorted of weird methods then went back and changed them when I found simpler ways, I think the docs need a bit work ;)

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for (and it's much simpler than I thought! :) )